# What is the recommended approach for GridDB data backup and restore process

Tags: griddb

I need to implement a data backup and restore mechanism for GridDB. What is the recommended approach to back up and restore data in GridDB? Should I manually copy and paste the file into a new data directory?

Answer (score 0):

GridDB Community Edition does not include an inherent backup functionality. But I believe you can always use the backup/export tool on their repo: https://github.com/griddb/expimp